# why ScrollView inside Animated.View not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to ask question here, i 've made draggable view using pan responder. i managed it to only move up and down. here is my pan responder config

```
this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (event, gesture) => true,
  // THIS TRACK MOVEMENT OF OUR FINGER 
  onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {
    if (gesture.dy > 0) {
      this.position.setValue({ y: gesture.dy });
    }
  },
  onPanResponderRelease: (event, gesture) => {
    if (gesture.dy > SWIPE_THRESHOLD) {
      this.forceSwipeDown();
    } else {
       this.resetPosition();
    }
  },
});
```

i use it in animated.view, here is the code

```
<Animated.View
       style={[modalCard, this.position.getLayout()]}
       {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
        {
          // XButton
        }
        <TouchableOpacity style={button} onPress={() => this.props.closeModal()}>
          <Icon 
            name='times'
            size={wp(20)}
            color='#A9A9A9'
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={topBorders}>
          <View style={doubeLine} />
        </View>
        {this.props.children}
      </Animated.View>
```

my question is, when i put ScrollView as children of this component, the scrollview wont scroll. i dont know why is it behave like this, thank you.

Comment: This could be due to the gesture handlers on the `Animated.View` overriding the ones on the `ScrollView`.

Comment: @Andrew i think the same with you. any workaround possible?

Answer (score 1):

On the `ScrollView`, there is a default JS pan responder. Here, you create the `PanResponder` in the `Animated.View`. In the negotiations process， `Animated.View` become the responder of the touches, while the `ScrollView` not.

#### Solution:

You can capture the touch events outside the `ScrollView` while ignore the touch events inside the `ScrollView`. By doing this, the `ScrollView` can scroll.

The code may like this:

```js
    _ignoreRegion = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    }


    _onLayout = ({
      nativeEvent: {
        layout: {
          x,
          y,
          width,
          height
        }
      }
    }) => {
      this._ignoreRegion = nativeEvent.layout;
    };

    _isInsideRegion = (x, y, region) => {
       return x >= region.x && x <= region.x + region.width && y >= region.y && y <= region.y + region.height;
    }

    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {
           if (this._isInsideRegion(evt.pageX, evt.pageY, this._ignoreRegion)) {
             return false; 
           } else {
             return true; 
           }
        },
        // .... 
    })
```

The JSX

```js
 <Animated.View {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}>            
    <ScrollView onLayout={this._onLayout}/>
</Animated.View>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to include a `ScrollView` inside `Animated.View` by configuring when `onMoveShouldSetPanResponder` (NOT `onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture` as suggested by [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59552578/9723036)) should return true. When it returns true, `Animated.View` will capture the sliding event. When it returns false, the sliding event is ignored by `Animated.View` and captured by whatever view is underneath. Thus, say we know the x-coord range of the `ScrollView` is `[xLo, xHi]` and the y-coord range is `[yLo, yHi]`, we can create a `panResponder` as such

```js
const panResponder = React.useRef(
  PanResponder.create({
    onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (_, {dx, dy, moveX, moveY}) => {
      if (xLo <= moveX && moveX <= xHi && yLo <= moveY && moveY <= yHi) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
  }),
).current;
```

This `panResponder` guarantees that `Animated.View` ignores all sliding event within the boundary set by `[xLo, xHi]` and `[yLo, yHi]`, but registers sliding events outside the boundary.

`[xLo, xHi]` and `[yLo, yHi]` can be obtained by the [`measure`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/direct-manipulation#measurecallback) callback.

Below is a demo implemented using this method. For more demos and source code, check the [documentation](https://github.com/FanchenBao/react-native-sliding-drawer/blob/master/docs/demos/scrollable.md).

Full disclosure, I am the author of [@fanchenbao/react-native-sliding-drawer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fanchenbao/react-native-sliding-drawer)
.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

I am using like this, and it's working on my project:

```
<Animated.View>
    <ScrollView>
        { this.renderMultimpleItems() }
    </ScrollView>
</Animated.View>
```